# Join the SQL Bridge table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, azure-sql-database

I have the following tables

**User**

```
+--------+------+
| UserID | Name |
+--------+------+
| User1  | John |
| User2  | Mike |
+--------+------+
```

**Device**

```
+----------+------------+------------+------+
| DeviceID | DeviceName | DeviceType | Good |
+----------+------------+------------+------+
|        1 | Device1    | A          |    0 |
|        2 | Device2    | A          |    1 |
|        3 | Device7    | B          |    0 |
|        4 | Device8    | B          |    1 |
|        5 | Device11   | C          |    0 |
|        6 | Device12   | C          |    1 |
+----------+------------+------------+------+
```

**UserDevice**

```
 +--------------+--------+----------+
| UserDeviceID | UserID | DeviceID |
+--------------+--------+----------+
| z            | User1  |        1 |
| y            | User1  |        3 |
| x            | User1  |        5 |
| w            | User2  |        2 |
| v            | User2  |        4 |
| u            | User2  |        6 |
+--------------+--------+----------+
```

I want to join these tables like below

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| UserName | DeviceTypeA | DeviceTypeB | DeviceTypeC |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| User1    | Device1     | Device7     | Device11    |
| User2    | Device2     | Device8     | Device22    |
+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I tried all types of join query but unfortunately, I could not get the data in the above format. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `PIVOT` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15))

```
SELECT P.[Name], P.A AS DeviceTypeA, P.B AS DeviceTypeB, P.C AS DeviceTypeC
   FROM
      (
         SELECT U.[Name], D.DeviceName, D.DeviceType
            FROM [User] U
            INNER JOIN DeviceUser DU
               ON DU.UserID = U.UserID
            INNER JOIN Device D
               ON D.DeviceID = DU.DeviceID
      ) AS X
      PIVOT
      (
         MAX(X.DeviceName)
         FOR X.DeviceType IN([A], [B], [C])
      ) AS P;
```

Note however that this will return only one device name for a certain user and device type even if there are more devices of a device type for a that user.